# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed dji package

Tags: package, ros, dji-sdk, launching

When i try to launch the package by typing

roslaunch dji_sdk sdk.launch

where the launch file content :

```
launch>
    <node pkg="dji_sdk" type="dji_sdk_node" name="dji_sdk" output="screen">
    <!-- node parameters -->
    <param name="serial_name" type="string" value="/dev/ttyTHS0"/>
    <param name="baud_rate" type="int" value="921600"/>
    <param name="app_id" type="int" value="1079440"/>
    <param name="app_version" type="int" value="1"/>
    <param name="align_time" type="bool" value="false"/>
    <param name="enc_key" type="string" value="39d353a8e9ad01b6c659111904bae57ebb138785aa5159699383f28da3f56563"/>
    <param name="use_broadcast" type="bool" value="false"/>
    </node>
</launch>
```

it gives me this error :

```
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: syntax error: line 1, column 0
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Comment: post up your sdk.launch and log file. so that others can help you

Comment: dji@manifold2:~/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
dji@manifold2:~/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws$ catkin_make
dji@manifold2:~/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws$ rosed dji_sdk sdk.launch 
dji@manifold2:~/Desktop/Ibtesam_ws$ roslaunch dji_sdk sdk.launch 
logging to /home/dji/.ros/log/4bf6ba22-eb1e-11e9-acf7-74da38ebc18f/roslaunch-manifold2-4798.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: syntax error: line 1, column 0
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

Comment: I started with sourcing the workspace and catkin_make after that i rosed the launch file to edit four things: value of app_id, enc_key, serial_name to ttyTHS0, and baud_rate. and then i tried to launch the dji_sdk sdk,launch however it replayed me with the error that i have previously shared.

Comment: please edit your post. upload error and content within the sdk.launch. high chance you made a syntax error inside. e.g missing " > or \ . shows content inside "/home/dji/.ros/log/4bf6ba22-eb1e-11e9-acf7-74da38ebc18f/roslaunch-manifold2-4798.log"  as well  . please re-think how others can help you

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai please check the post now

Comment: is   <launch> natually launch>  or did you miss out <

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai actually it was downloaded along with dji sdk package so i don't know.

Comment: adding <  it back. does it help?

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai yes it did, but  i got another error, which i post about it earlier today

Comment: ..bro high chance it is another small mistake. in real world, no one is going to follow you all the way and help you troubleshoot. you need to read and error and understand them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error here was because of missing < in the first line.